# Incorrect matrix value being retrieved when calling an x86 Assembly function from a C program

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

I am writing a C program that adds the values of two cells in two matrices. In my C program, I call an Assembly function that implements the function to add the two cells. That function has the following signature:

```
// Adds two matrix cells together and returns the result
int addTwoCells(int **matrixA, int aRows, int aColumns, int cellARow, int cellAColumn,
        int **matrixB, int bRows, int bColumns, int cellBRow, int cellBColumn);
```

Below is my C program (`main.c`): I am defining 2 dynamically allocated 3x3 matrices, with the bottom right corner of each matrix set to 3. I am intenting to add the bottom right corners through the function call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Adds two matrix cells together and returns the result
int addTwoCells(int **matrixA, int aRows, int aColumns, int cellARow, int cellAColumn,
        int **matrixB, int bRows, int bColumns, int cellBRow, int cellBColumn);

int main(void) {
    // Define the dimensions for matrix A
    int rA = 3;
    int cA = 3;

    // Define the double pointer that defines matrix A
    int **matrixA;
    // Dynamically allocate space for the entire matrix
    matrixA = (int**) malloc(rA * sizeof(int*));
    // Dynamically allocate sufficient space for each row in the entire matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++) {
        matrixA[i] = (int*) malloc(cA * sizeof(int));
    }

    matrixA[2][2] = 3;

    // Define the dimensions for matrix B
    int rB = 3;
    int cB = 3;

    // Define the double pointer that defines matrix B
    int **matrixB;
    // Dynamically allocate space for the entire matrix
    matrixB = (int**) malloc(rB * sizeof(int*));
    // Dynamically allocate sufficient space for each row in the entire matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < rB; i++) {
        matrixB[i] = (int*) malloc(cB * sizeof(int));
    }

    matrixB[2][2] = 3;

    // Test calling the matrix multiplication function using the static library
    // compiled from the Assembly file
    printf("%d\n", addTwoCells(matrixA, rA, cA, 2, 2, matrixB, rB, cB, 2, 2));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Below is my x86 Assembly program (`addTwoCells.s`). I first process in all the parameters and then I try to retrieve the value of the cell at the bottom right corner of the first matrix. To do this, I first compute the flattened index corresponding to the bottom right corner (which after debugging is correct: `2*(column count) + 2 = 2*3 + 2 = 8`). However, when I try to retrieve the integer at that flattened index + the memory address of the first matrix (`matrixAStartingAddress`), **the result is always a crazy large number (like 1478295976) when it should be 3**, as shown in the output of the function (stored in the EAX register). This seems strange, since it seems that I am processing the parameters correctly and am moving the value at the memory address `%ecx` through the expression `(%ecx)`, not the memory address itself:

```
# Function signature:
# int addTwoMatrixCells(int **matrixA, int aRows, int aColumns, int cellARow, int cellAColumn,
# int **matrixB, int bRows, int BColumns, int cellBRow, int cellBColumn)

.data
    # Matrix A dimensions
    aRows:
        .int 0

    aColumns:
        .int 0

    # Coordinate of cell A
    cellARow:
        .int 0

    cellAColumn:
        .int 0

    # Matrix B dimensions
    bRows:
        .int 0

    bColumns:
        .int 0

    # Coordinate of cell B
    cellBRow:
        .int 0

    cellBColumn:
        .int 0

    # The starting memory address of matrix A
    matrixAStartingAddress:
        .int 0

    # The starting memory address of matrix B
    matrixBStartingAddress:
        .int 0

.text
# Defining a function addTwoMatrixCells
.global addTwoCells
addTwoCells:
    # Prologue
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    # Process in parameter 1: the starting memory address of matrix A
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, matrixAStartingAddress

    # Process in parameter 2: the number of rows in matrix A
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, aRows

    # Process in parameter 3: the number of columns in matrix A
    movl 16(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, aColumns

    # Process in parameter 4: the row index of cellA
    movl 20(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, cellARow

    # Process in parameter 5: the column index of cellA
    movl 24(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, cellAColumn

    # Process in parameter 6: the number of rows in matrix B
    movl 28(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, bRows

    # Process in parameter 7: the number of columns in matrix B
    movl 32(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, bColumns

    # Process in parameter 8: the row index of cellB
    movl 36(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, cellBRow

    # Process in parameter 9: the column index of cellB
    movl 40(%ebp), %ecx
    movl %ecx, cellBColumn

    # Compute the flattened index of the cell in matrix A
    # One of the arithmetic operators needs to be in a CUP register
    # In this case, we designate ECX register to store the number of columns
    # in matrix A (n) initially, but ECX after the computation will store
    # the memory address of cellA in the matrix
    movl aColumns, %ecx
    imul cellARow, %ecx
    addl cellAColumn, %ecx
    addl matrixAStartingAddress, %ecx
    movl (%ecx), %eax

    # Compute the flattened index of the cell in matrix B

    # Epilogue
    movl %ebp, %esp
    pop %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Two problems I think: 1) your matrix is not flat, it's an array of row pointers. 2) assembly uses byte indexing, you don't seem to scale neither by element size nor by pointer size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1: You forgot the starting memory address of matrix B. It should be parameter 6, and what you currently call parameters 6-9 should become 7-10.

Problem 2: `int`s are 4 bytes wide in x86, but you're calculating the address of the cell as if they're only 1 byte wide.

Problem 3: You're passing a double pointer from C to `addTwoCells`, but your assembly code treats it like it's a 2D array. These are not compatible types. Try [compiling these two C functions and comparing the resulting assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Yb4o1z):

```c
int readValuePtr(int rows, int cols, int cellRow, int cellCol, int **matrix) {
    return matrix[cellRow][cellCol];
}

int readValueArr(int rows, int cols, int cellRow, int cellCol, int matrix[rows][cols]) {
    return matrix[cellRow][cellCol];
}
```